# ZF2 - different error messages with NotEmpty validator

Tags: php, zend-framework

I got stuck with this stupid error messages in Zend Framework 2. Spent two hours and nothing, I still got two different error messages with NotEmpty validator.

```
$nameNotEmptyMessage = 'Pole wymagane';

$inputFilter->add(array(
     'name' => 'name',
     'required' => true,
     'filters' => array(
          new Filter\StringTrim()
     ),
     'validators' => array(
         new Validator\NotEmpty(array(
             'messages' => array(
                 Validator\NotEmpty::INVALID => $nameNotEmptyMessage,
                 Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => $nameNotEmptyMessage
             )
         ))
     )
));
```

And what? It works pretty cool when I send form with "name" element inside it. When it's empty, I've got my message. But, when I send form without the "name" element inside it, the message is still "Value is required and can't be empty"! Why?

I need to have in both cases the same message because sometimes the form won't have "name" element.

Thank you guys very much!

Comment: So if the `name` element is not submitted at all, you don't want the field to be validated?  Is that your question?

Comment: No at all. If "name" element is not submitted, I want to have message "pole wymagane" as I have this message when "name" fields is submitted but it's empty. Now I've default message is this case: "Value is required and can't be empty"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for replying to the comment to clarify the problem.  First I must say, I feel your pain on this one.  After having not used ZF2 for over a year and spending some time figuring this out, it highlights yet another painful thing in ZF2.

That said, here is my *simple* solution.  Not necessary correct, or the best way to go about it but it solves your problem with the least amount of code.  **In your controller where you instantiate and validate the form, add this code** before you call `new Form`:

```
if (!isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $this->getRequest()
         ->setPost(
             new \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters(
                 array('name' => '')
             )
         );
}
```

This seemed the simplest route rather than setting up a default validation translator and adding a duplicate message.  It is just checking to see if the `name` field was not present, and if so sets it with any empty value.

Now the reason why we have to do this:

This happens because of how `\Zend\InputFilter\Input` works.  When the InputFilter runs, it sees the element is *missing*.  It then checks the `required` property, sees it's true but the input has **no value**.  No value being different than **empty**.

When the filter is required but has no input, `\Zend\InputFilter\Input::prepareRequiredValidationFailureMessage` is called.  If you look at the source of that function, you'll see:

```
protected function prepareRequiredValidationFailureMessage()
{
    $notEmpty = new NotEmpty();
    $templates = $notEmpty->getOption('messageTemplates');
    return [
        NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => $templates[NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY],
    ];
}
```

Notice how it creates a new `NotEmpty` validator and fetches its default message, thus bypassing the translation you set within the InputFilter.

The alternative:

One alternative, which may be more correct, but also requires more code and could arguably be more confusing looking back later would be to create a new class implementing `\Zend\Validator\Translator\TranslatorInterface` and set an array with the translation for that message and then calling `\Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator` passing that so the default translator will be used on that message.

This is just difficult because there is no short way of setting up that object because of how the classes are inherited and I wasn't able to find a quick solution to set up the default translator with just that message.  Also, if you have another translator in place, it might interfere with it.

So it seems the simplest thing is to just check for the absence of that form field and populate it with any empty value if it's missing.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's really annoying and I hate problems like this. Your first solution is good, maybe not so pretty, but it'll just work and this is what I need right now :) Thanks!

Comment: Glad that will work - it's what I'd use in my project over anything else.  And I forgot to mention this in the post: I like ZF2 and it's a very good MVC + more library which I still use, but every once in a while you run into "gotcha's" like this that take hours to solve when the goal is something fairly simple, or so you thought :)

Answer (score 0):

Other more simple way to fix this is to overwrite the Form setData($data) and to check if $data['name'] is set. Something like this:

```
public function setData($data)
{
    if(!isset($data['name'])){
        $data['name'] = '';
    }

    return parent::setData($data);
}
```